# Yii Gridview show/hide columns from interface when filtering the records

Tags: yii2, yii-extensions, yii2-advanced-app

I am using the YII Gridview want to show/hide columns when filtering the records
Ex: If Name, City, State and phone is listing, I want checkbox to show/hide any of columns like Phone, Name in listing.
Please suggest.

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: I can do it with data table but want to do it with Gridview.

Comment: i mean , show your effort. what you tried so far.

Answer (score 5):

you can use the visible attribute of gridview column fields

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'your_attribute1',
        ....
        [
            'label' => 'your_labe',
            'attribute_n' => 'your_attribute',
             'visible' => ( $your_condition == 'value_for_visible') 
        ],
        ......
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to use 'visible' option for that. just pass the condition in which condition you need to visible that column. Like This :

```
 <?php echo GridView::widget( [
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
    ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
    ['attribute'=>'your_column',
    'visible'=> if ( $data->field_name == "some_value" ) ? true : false,
    'value'=>function( $data ) {
        return !empty( $data->your_column ) ? $data->your_column : '0.5';
    },
    ]
    ] );?>
```